# Attached Properties in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, attached-properties

I am using an attached property to limit the input into textboxes and textblocks to either numeric or alphabetic. Now I would like to apply this attached property to a datagridtextcolumn. 
I tried the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Max" Width="50"
                                  Binding="{Binding Path=Max, Mode=TwoWay"
                                  Helper:InputService.NumericOnly="True">
```

and something like this:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                      <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Helper:InputService.NumericOnly" Value="True"/>
                      </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

But it does not work.
How do I do it right?

My InputService contains the NumericOnly property:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty NumericOnlyProperty =          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     "NumericOnly",
     typeof(bool),
     typeof(InputService),
     new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnNumericOnlyChanged));


public static bool GetNumericOnly(DependencyObject d)
{
  return (bool)d.GetValue(NumericOnlyProperty);
}


public static void SetNumericOnly(DependencyObject d, bool value)
{
  d.SetValue(NumericOnlyProperty, value);
}

private static void OnNumericOnlyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  bool isNumericOnly = (bool)e.NewValue;

  if (d is TextBox)
  {
    var textBox = (TextBox)d;

    if (isNumericOnly)
    {
      textBox.PreviewTextInput += BlockNonDigitCharacters;
      textBox.PreviewKeyDown += ReviewKeyDown;
    }
    else
    {
      textBox.PreviewTextInput -= BlockNonDigitCharacters;
      textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= ReviewKeyDown;
    }
  }
  else if (d is TextBlock)
  {
    var textBlock = (TextBlock)d;

    if (isNumericOnly)
    {
      textBlock.PreviewTextInput += BlockNonDigitCharacters;
      textBlock.PreviewKeyDown += ReviewKeyDown;
    }
    else
    {
      textBlock.PreviewTextInput -= BlockNonDigitCharacters;
      textBlock.PreviewKeyDown -= ReviewKeyDown;
    }
  }
}


private static void BlockNonDigitCharacters(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (char ch in e.Text)
  {
    if (Char.IsDigit(ch))
    {
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the property, not much to say here without any information on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this it what works for me:

```
         <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
              <Setter Property="Helper:InputService.NumericOnly" Value="True"/>
            </Style>
          </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your property implementation expects only to be set on a `TextBox` or `TextBlock`.  I would suggest that you put a breakpoint in your code and check what type of control it's actually being set on - I suspect you'll find it's the parent container of your cell, rather than the text control itself.

EDIT: based on your comment, you probably want to include the following in your binding:

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Max, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This will cause the binding to refresh every time the property changes, where the default for most input controls is to fire when a control loses focus.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in the first line of OnNumericOnlyChanged, it is never reached.

Comment: Now I found that the breakpoint is reached, but only after the enter key was pressed. I would like to have the input checked immediately, since otherwise my converter used for the binding of the datagridtextcolumn would throw exceptions. How could I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the hint Dan. Unfortunately that still does not work. The OnNumericOnlyChanged is only reached after the enter key was hit, no matter what UpdateSourceTrigger is set (FocusLost or PropertyChanged). Even if I removed the converter there was no difference.

Comment: It looks like what I really want is to attach my property only to the cell if it is in editing mode. If I use a PreviewTextInput handler directly within EditinElementStyle, it works like expected. How could I use my attached property here so I don't have to write the code behind?